# MaterialApp.router not rebuilding its sub-routes

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc, flutter-go-router

I have an `MaterialApp.router` which is wrapped inside `BlocBuilder`, something like below.

```
BlocBuilder<MyCubit, MyState>(
  builder: (context, state) {
    debugPrint('Material app rebuilds :)');

    return MaterialApp.router(
      ...
      routerConfig: AppRouter.router, // instance of GoRouter
    );
  }
```

The `AppRouter.router` is defined as follows, where the `initialLocation` is set to `/home`. In the `HomeScreen()`, details of the current active user are showcased. The `HomeScreen()` also have a button that can change the current user, and consequently `MyState` also updates.

```
static final router = GoRouter(
  ...
  initialLocation: '/home',
  routes: <RouteBase>[
    GoRoute(path: '/test', pageBuilder: (_, __) => const TestWidgetScreen()),
    GoRoute(path: '/intro', pageBuilder: (_, __) => const IntroScreen()),
    GoRoute(path: '/home', pageBuilder: (_, __) => const HomeScreen()),
  ],
);
```

Whenever, the current user changes by tapping the button in `HomeScreen()`, `MyState` also updates and consequently the `MaterialApp.router` also rebuilds as it is dependent upon `MyState`. However, `HomeScreen()` not updates at all, even though it's parent, which is `MaterialApp.router` rebuilds. What is happing here, and what are the remedies ?

I have implemented a separate `BlocBuilder` in `HomeScreen`, which is working by the way.